# Facebook Application Tab -> External Linking with jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to customize the content rendered in my app by controlling the **app_data** string parameter.

As [documented by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs#params) this should be possible, but I can only find solutions done with PHP, and I would like to achieve this with jQuery.

If my app URL is **http://www.facebook.com/YourPage?v=app_1234567890&app_data=?product** I want to display ***section#products*** and if my app URL is **http://www.facebook.com/YourPage?v=app_1234567890&app_data=?about** I want to display ***section#about***, and so on.

Can anyone please help me out with a working example?

Answer (score 0):

The `app_data` parameter will be in the `signed_request` variable, which is POSTed to your URL, so you must use PHP (or another server language).

Check out the docs for more information about `signed_request`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request